# Custom key binding motion not working in vim/neovim

Tags: vim, neovim

```vim
nnoremap j n
nnoremap k e
nnoremap l u
nnoremap h i
inoremap jj <esc>
       
nnoremap e j
nnoremap u k
nnoremap i l
nnoremap n h
```

I have configured these custom mappings. When i use them it perfectly works, also with motion like `2e` it will work as `2j` and go two lines down. But the problem is when i want to perform `d2j` to delete two lines, my binding doesn't work and when hitting the key with `d2` or as a motion the key is rendered as it is i.e.
when i type `d2e` it should be doing `d2j` but it does `d2e` instead how can I configure this?

Comment: You need to provide the matching *operator-pending mode* mappings. See `:help :onoremap` and `:help mapmode-o`.

Comment: Hey can you be more specific about what I have to do cause I am new and all these seems confusing btw thanks for your time.

Comment: If you are new, you certainly have more important things to do than randomly reassigning keybindings. `:help user-manual` is your best starting point.

Comment: Also, `vimtutor` does a good job of introducing to Vim and taking away the confusion.

Answer (score 2):

Vim is modal in nature, means it has different modes and depending on the mode,
you can do different things. Vim starts in *normal mode* which offers powerful
commands for navigation and text editing. You'll also undoubtedly know *insert mode* because
that's where you write text. To get back to *normal mode*, you came up with the
mapping
`:inoremap jj <esc>` which is active only in insert mode (note the leading `i`).
BTW, it's not related to your other mappings so let's leave it like that.

All your other mappings are created with the `:nnoremap` command, meaning they
will work only in normal mode.
This is a good thing, you would hardly want them in insert mode. Imagine hitting
<kbd>J</kbd> and seeing an `n` appear in your text.

A lesser-known mode is *operator-pending mode* and that's the mode Vim is in
when you type e.g. `d` and Vim waits for a motion. To make
your mappings work there, use `:onoremap`.

Before long, you'll want to select text in *visual mode* and wonder why the
mappings don't work there, as well. Use the `:vnoremap` command.

Your mappings, repeated for visual and operator-pending modes will look like the following:

```
nnoremap j n
onoremap j n
vnoremap j n
nnoremap k e
onoremap k e
vnoremap k e
nnoremap l u
onoremap l u
vnoremap l u
nnoremap h i
onoremap h i
vnoremap h i
       
nnoremap e j
onoremap e j
vnoremap e j
nnoremap u k
onoremap u k
vnoremap u k
nnoremap i l
onoremap i l
vnoremap i l
nnoremap n h
onoremap n h
vnoremap n h
```

You write in your comment that you're new and there's no shame in that. If
you're new to Vim, you should know how to read the built-in `:help`, you only
need to type `:help` in normal mode, optionally followed by the command you're
curious about. <kbd>Ctrl-D</kbd> will give you suggestions. `:help` should
be your first stop to get information on Vim. Not Google, not SO.

As it turns out, `:help map-modes` has all the information you need. You could
also jump to `:help :nnoremap` and read a little above, below and referenced
topics.

Generally, when learning Vim, I'm convinced it's best to start with the bare
editor itself and learn its core features before going crazy with mappings,
plugins and other additions. With your switched keys, it will be hard for you to
follow any tutorial on Vim without mentally undoing your mappings. Seriously think about it before copying the stuff I wrote above to your `vimrc`.

While `hjkl` were chosen because somebody drew arrows on those keys half a century ago, some of the other commands you
map follow mnemonics like `u`ndo, `e`nd-of-word, etc. which are now lost.

Mastering Vim isn't how much you bend and break that thing but how well you can play it. Learning the piano, you wouldn't rip out all the black keys and put them to the right of the white keys because it looks more tidy that way.

I can't say I understand the motivation for creating these mappings. It looks a
little bit like you're using a Dvorak keyboard, only the `n` doesn't fit in the
picture. As an exception to the "new users shouldn't use plugins" rule I made
above, if you're using an esoteric keyboard layout, consider looking for an existing
plugin to make the keyboard work.